# $ t(n) = t( x_1 x_2 x_3 ...) = t(x_1) + t(x_2) + t(x_3) + ... + t( x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... ) $

Tags: number-theory, inequality, asymptotics, functional-equations, closed-form

Let $ n > 1 $ be an integer.

Consider The prime factorization

$$ n = x_1 x_2 x_3 ... $$

Now define

$$ t(n) = t( x_1 x_2 x_3 ...) = t(x_1) + t(x_2) + t(x_3) + ... + t( x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... ) $$

Clearly this function is completely determined by its values at primes. This gives us multiple solutions.

Im fascinated by this function.

Has this been studied before ?

—-

Some more specific questions :

Can we find solutions such that

$$ t(n) \leq t(n+1) \leq t(n+2) $$

And if so , which one grows the slowest ?
And how fast does that slowest solution grow asymptotically ?

How about The fastest ?

Are they easy questions or do they depend on a lot of theory or open conjectures ?

A reference or a few plots would be nice too.

Im not sure how to handle this.

—-

Update :

There seems to be a problem with defining $t(2n)$ so for now i focus on odd $n$.

From $t(3^{3^k}) $ we conclude that f grows like $ O( ln(n) + ln(ln(n)) + ln(ln(ln(n))) + ... ) $

Comment: The $x_i$ are not NEC distinct ! In case that might confuse.

Comment: I am not sure your function is well-defined. What is $t(p^k)$, just for my understanding?

Comment: $t(p^k) = t(p p p ... ) $ that is what i meant by not necc distinct !

Comment: For instance $t(8) = t( 2 *2 *2 ) = t(2) + t(2) + t(2) + t(2+2+2) =  3 t(2) + t(6) $ or $ t(p^k) = k t(p) + t(p k) $ for $ k > 1$.

Comment: In such a case "the" prime factorization is not unique, and I am still uncertain about yours being a *definition* of $t$. Let us suppose $t(p)$ has been fixed for any prime $p$: what is $t(p^3)$, considering that $p^3=p\cdot p^2=p\cdot p\cdot p$?

Comment: @Jack No, that's quite clear: $t(p^3)=3t(p)+t(3p)=4t(p)+t(3)$. I have another question, though: how do you define $t(4)$?

Comment: Hmmm good point Ivan

Comment: There is no problem with $f(2n)$. There is one with $f(4)$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: why not $t(p^3)=t(p^2)+t(p)+t(p+p^2)$ which is potentially different from $3t(p)+t(3p)$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It just seemed natural to me that we should go all the way down to the primes. But then again, it is for the OP to decide.

Comment: Yes Ivan if we set $t(2) = 0 $ and give a value to $t(4)$. But i think that the proposed inequality $t(n+2)>=t(n+1) >= t(n) $ does not hold in this case ... then again $ t(n + 2) >= t(n) $ might fail anyway for odd n as well independent of our choices of values for $t(2) , t(4), t(p)$. Thinking ... perhaps $t(2 n)$ is more intresting than $t(2 n + 1)$